# Change iBook Dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ipad

is there any way to change iBook dictionary ? any language instead of English ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only english and japanese is available at present:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4059

Comment: so what about jailbroken iPad? :D i think ibook use dictionary database same as mac os x dictionary right ?

Comment: hi this is very full for me .than q

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if your device is jailbroken.
[Here is detailed instructions how to setup dictionary to translate from Italian to English](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=17406146&postcount=35).
Instead of Italian you can use any dictionary. It may be a dictionary with translations (from any lang to English, or from English to any lang) or a dictionary with definitions.
Its works in iOS 6.1.*